# Apache Storm：KafkaSpout has a lot of failed tuples due to timeout

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm

In my processtime-window wordcount topology, the input rate is 2000 tuple/s. The window size of my count_bolt is 3s and 1s lag. It can be seen from the UI that there are a large number of failed tuples. By looking at the logs, the reason for the tuple failure is timeout. I also set the `TOPOLOGY_MAX_SPOUT_PENDING` to 10000，`topology.message.timeout.secs` to 60. And according to the two parameters of `Capacity` and `Execute latency` in the figure, the parallelism of the bolt should be sufficient.

**Q:** How should I adjust the parameters?  For example, `TOPOLOGY_MAX_SPOUT_PENDING` ，`topology.message.timeout.secs` or something else.

This is a picture of my storm UI：
[storm UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1jAL.png)

Answer (score 0):

I would start by lowering `topology.max.spout.pending`. Once you have a topology that isn't uselessly processing already timed out tuples, it should be easier to tell where your bottleneck is.

Keep in mind that the capacity/execute latency only takes into account how much time is spent in `execute` for each tuple.

As I recall the Kafka bolt doesn't ack tuples before it leaves `execute`, but instead delivers the tuple to the producer and acks the tuple via a callback from the producer, which can happen after `execute` returns. As a result, you won't see the actual time spent processing tuples in a Kafka bolt reflected in the capacity/execute latency. You can see the actual time between the tuple arriving at `execute` and the tuple being acked in the process latency, which is pretty high.

Your count_bolt process latency is also high, so take a look at whether that one is also buffering up tuples before acking them.

Comment: Thanks. My count_bolt uses processtime-window，so one tuple buffered for 3 seconds. So should I adjust `TOPOLOGY_MAX_SPOUT_PENDING` from small to large? Do I need to increase `topology.message.timeout.secs`?

Comment: I don't know what processtime-window is. No, I would lower max spout pending. I doubt increasing the timeout would help you.